# Parámetros Fecha Power BI

Tags: sql, powerbi

Tengo una tabla con 3 variables: Id (Incidencia) con 123, 124, 125, etc., Fecha Apertura con 27/01/2023,28/01/2023,etc. y Fecha Finalización con 28/01/2023, 29/01/2023,etc. La fecha de Apertura de cada incidencia no coincide con la fecha de finalización de esa incidencia, ya que pasan varios días para cerrarse la incidencia. Por eso, lo que quiero es un filtro o parámetro en el que si pongo fecha de apertura me salgan todas las incidencias con la fecha de apertura filtrada y si pongo fecha de finalización me ponga todas las incidencias con la fecha de finalización. Por ejemplo, para el 01/01/2023 puede tener 3 incidencias abiertas con la fecha de apertura y 5 finalizadas con la fecha de finalización.

Lo que he hecho ha sido crear un Nuevo Parámetro con PowerBi que se llama 'Tipo fecha' con las fechas de Apertura y Finalización y he creado una columna nueva en mi Tabla Original que se llama Fecha Mostrada con la siguiente fórmula: "Fecha Mostrada = if(SELECTEDVALUE('Tipo Fecha'[Tipo Fecha]) = "FechaFinalizacion", Retencion[FechaAperturaAviso], Retencion[FechaFinalizacion])".

Esto me está dando error, otra opción que tengo hecha son marcadores creados, pero el problema que tengo es que los filtros que tengo en la página con cada marcador se me borran porque es como que se me actualizan.

¿Sabríais como es la mejor manera de presentarlo o me debería quedar con la opción de los marcadores?

Saludos,